# Trying to understand a query (LEFT JOIN and subquery)

Tags: sql

I've been trying to understand the behavior of a query but i dont fully understand what is going on.

Take a look:

```
SELECT main.entity_id,main.sku,name.value AS name
FROM product_entity AS main 
LEFT JOIN product_entity_varchar AS name ON main.entity_id = name.entity_id
WHERE name.attribute_id = (
    SELECT attribute_id 
    FROM ger_attribute 
    WHERE attribute_code LIKE "name"
    AND 'entity_type_id' = (
        SELECT entity_type_id
        FROM ger_entity_type
        WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product_info'
    )
)
```

[image]

Can you please explain why it is using a **subquery** ,why the LEFT JOIN is important in these cases and the condition **entity_type_code = 'catalog_product_info'**?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Usually help requested as: a) I have such and such data, b) I need this result, c) help me to write my query. Your help request quite strange: you have query and you need to understand your data? It's strange but could be OK. Start with description of tables, relations between them and samples of data.

Comment: @AlexYu Hi!. I am not an expert and i am not 100% sure of my steps :( thats why i asked this question.. thats all

Comment: you have SQL-query written by someone else and you trying to understand how this query works, right? Supply samples of data in `product_entity_varchar`, `ger_attribute`, `ger_entity_type` and result of query. After that: formulate again your question: what is it strange/incorrect/unclear for you. Help us to help you!

Comment: When would you use LEFT JOIN or INNER JOIN if you are gathering information from different tables?

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` could be decomposed as  `UNION ALL` of  `INNER JOIN` query + `NOT EXISTS`-query. If this can help - I can demonstrate such decomposition

Comment: @AlexYu It would be awesome.. thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187404/discussion-between-alex-yu-and-programming-amazing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT main.entity_id,main.sku,name.value AS name
FROM product_entity AS main 
LEFT JOIN product_entity_varchar AS name ON main.entity_id = name.entity_id
...
```

The query starts by pulling out table  `product_entity`. The `LEFT JOIN` allows the query to access the record(s) in table `product_entity_varchar` whose `entity_id` is equal to the value of the column that has the same name in `product_entity`.

In the resultset, the value of column `value` from table `product_entity_varchar` is displayed, under alias `name`.

The keyword `LEFT` makes the relation optional ; it there is no matching record in `product_entity_varchar`, the name will simply appear as `NULL` in the output. If it were an `[INNER] JOIN`, then the relation would be mandatory : unmatched records would be filtered out, and would not appear in the output.

Comment: Thank you for replying! Dude,in this case i used a left join to include all entries from the main table and exclude possible values in value table without a product relation. What would have happened if i had used inner join instead of left join?

Comment: @programming_amazing : you seem to be looking for a *mandatory* relation. If so, you actually want to use `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Just a question, in my example: Why would you use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN? What would be the main difference?

Comment: @programming_amazing : well, that's exactly what I tried to explain in my answer...

Comment: Oh, yeah... i was thinking about this: "why someone would like to have NULL in the output? What would be the benefit of it?"

Answer (score 0):

OK. Let's clarify what is `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in SQL.

`LEFT JOIN` queries could be understood as just syntax abbreviation of `UNION ALL` of `INNER JOIN`-ed and `NOT EXIST`-ed queries.

Let's decompose `LEFT JOIN`-ed query:

```
SELECT main.entity_id,main.sku,name.value AS name
FROM 
    product_entity AS main 
    LEFT JOIN product_entity_varchar AS name ON main.entity_id = name.entity_id
WHERE 
    name.attribute_id = (
        SELECT attribute_id 
        FROM ger_attribute 
        WHERE attribute_code LIKE "name"
        AND 'entity_type_id' = (
            SELECT entity_type_id
            FROM ger_entity_type
            WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product_info'
        )
)
```

Is equivalent to:

```
SELECT main.entity_id,main.sku,name.value AS name
FROM 
    product_entity AS main 
    JOIN product_entity_varchar AS name 
        ON main.entity_id = name.entity_id
WHERE 
    name.attribute_id = (
        SELECT attribute_id 
        FROM ger_attribute 
        WHERE attribute_code LIKE "name"
        AND 'entity_type_id' = (
            SELECT entity_type_id
            FROM ger_entity_type
            WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product_info'
        )
    )
UNION ALL
SELECT main.entity_id,main.sku, NULL AS name -- <-- Attention!
FROM 
    product_entity AS main 
    NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT * FROM  product_entity_varchar AS name 
        WHERE 
            main.entity_id = name.entity_id
            AND name.attribute_id = (
                SELECT attribute_id 
                FROM ger_attribute 
                WHERE attribute_code LIKE "name"
                AND 'entity_type_id' = (
                    SELECT entity_type_id
                    FROM ger_entity_type
                    WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product_info'
                )
        )
    )
```

I hope this will help to understand query, although it's impossible without data to answer "why it is using a subquery" etc.